# Openstack to Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, openstack, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

this is my first post in StackOverFlow and I hope you can help me.
I am working to a important project about make a cluster or cloud with Raspberry Pi2. At this moment I got to create a cluster with MPI, but I don't get make a cloud.
I have searched a lot of information about Openstack with RP2 but still I have tried to use all  and don't got my objective.

I have used the different GitHub repos  and http://docs.openstack.org websit and worked to Ubuntu 14.04, but anything.

Well,, I need your help. What OS is the best to install OpenStack toRaspberry pi 2? And how ( some website, manual...)?

I AM WORKING WITH PHYSICAL RASPBERRY PI 2, NOT VIRTUAL.

Thank you .

Answer (score 3):

Well it is a couple of years old now, but I think the most comprehensive answer to your question is encapsulated in this blog post:

http://openstack.prov12n.com/openstack-on-raspberry-pi-part-1-why/

That being said, I'd like to point out that perhaps the 32-bit architecture of the Pi is maybe not optimal for openstack.  Another option you should look at is docker on the raspberry pi, without the overhead of the full openstack most applications run faster (this is true given just about any hardware).  So I'd suggest you start here:

http://blog.hypriot.com/

and if you want something more powerful (* and correspondingly more complex) try kubernetes on the Pi:

https://github.com/luxas/kubernetes-on-arm